# How to override a non-templated method in a templated subclass

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    virtual int foo() const = 0;
};

template <typename T = int>
class B : public A{
public:
    virtual int foo() const override;
};

int B::foo(){ return 3; }

int main(){
    B<int> b;
    cout << "b.foo()=" << b.foo() << endl;
}
```

And I get the following error with clang++:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 template_override.cpp
template_override.cpp:16:5: error: expected a class or namespace
int B::foo(){ return 3; }
    ^
1 error generated.
```

My question is, how do I implement the method `foo()` in class B where it seems like I cannot use template parameters?

I've tried making `B::foo()` into `B<>::foo()` but that doesn't work also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foo` definition has missing `const` and isn't a template:

```
   template <typename T>
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   int B<T>::foo() const { return 3; }
//      ^^^       ^^^^^^
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e1f47a3ca69eef7))

Remember, `B` is not a class; `B` is a class template.

`B<T>` (for some `T`) is a class.

Comment: Sorry, I made this as a toy example and made a mistake translating from my real code. Updated the question.

Comment: @Inunno: Here you go.

Comment: To be honest I find it hard to believe that your C++ book doesn't cover how to define the member functions of a class template.

Comment: Ok, that worked, there must be something wrong with my production code, thanks! This is probably a useless question now.

Comment: Thanks for the rep anyway